# How to dynamically update form data in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and I am trying to create a review system, whereby each team member reviews all the other members within their team.

Here is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models  
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Trait(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Review(models.Model):     
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                    related_name='reviewer_id')
    reviewee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                    related_name='reviewee_id')
    trait = models.ForeignKey(Trait, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trait_score = models.IntegerField()` return
```

This is my views.py file:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
 from review.forms import ReviewForm
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 from accounts.models import UserProfile

 def positivity_review(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
     form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
         return redirect('/review/relationships')
     else:
         form = ReviewForm()
         users = UserProfile.objects.filter(review_team=1)
         args = {'form': form, 'team_members': users}
         return render(request, 'review/positivity.html', args)` return
```

This is my forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import NumberInput
from review.models import Team, Review

class RangeInput(NumberInput):
    input_type = 'range'


class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    trait_score = forms.IntegerField(widget=RangeInput, min_value=0, 
    max_value=100, label='')

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = (
            'trait_score',    
            )` return
```

This is the HTML file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Review</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<br>
<h1>Review</h1>
<h2>Do they foster a postive climate?</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p>Exhibits a lack of awareness for a positive climate. Resistance to prompting.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p>Cooperates at times, within structured activities and friendly under prompting.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p>Cooperates within the team environment without prompting.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p>Cooperates well with others, enthusiastic and positve. Occationally prompts others to engage positively.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>Seeks to continuously and consistently create a positive environment. Acts as a role model for the team through prompting being supportive and encouraging and showing genuine concern for others.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <form method="post">
    {% for user in team_members %}
      <p>Reviewing: {{ user.first_name }}  {{ user.last_name }}</p>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
    {% endfor %}
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Next</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}`
```

Currently I am passing in the queryset through the views.py into the html file and looping through it to load the relevant number of team members.

Since I am loading a form each time for each individual in the team, how can I make the form submit so that it knows who is being reviewed? For example, submitting the reviewer, trait and score is simple as most of that can be passed directly into the view, however, submitting the reviewee (person being reviewed) is the part im not sure how to handle, as they are loaded within the form using the template tagging. I was wondering if it is possible to submit some kind of data back into the form such as first + last name or thier user id, anything so that when I go to publish the results I have a way of filtering individuals results.

Hopefully the description is sufficient. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really need to explain more

Comment: I updated the description as best I could, @Ramtin hopefully it makes a little more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this might be the answer.

First, create a simple form (rather than `ModelForm`) and add this, among other things:

```
pk = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'type': 'hidden',
        }
    ),
    label=''
)
```

This will hold the `pk` of the reviewee and won't be visible to reviewer.

Then, in the html file, I think you have to generate a separate form for each user rather than only the input (I'm not sure, try it). You can do this:

```
{% for user in team_members %}

    <form method="post" id="review_form_{{user.pk}}">

        <p>Reviewing: {{ user.first_name }}  {{ user.last_name }}</p>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Next</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#review_form_{{user.pk}}').children('#id_pk').val("{{user.pk}}");
    </script>
{% endfor %}
```

Remember that when django generates a form, each input will have to get an id and django adds `id_` to the beginning of the name of the field you create in `fields.py`

And lastly, when the reviewer submit a form, you can find your reveiwee in `views.py` this way:

```
form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    reviewee_id = request.POST.get('pk')
    reviewee = User.objects.get(pk=reviewee_id)
```

Comment: I've implemented the basic form and it works much better, so thank you. Only thing is the script doesn't set the value of the hidden field at all, I've tried heaps of different combinations but it doesn't seem to load anything at all.

Comment: @CMcAdam have you imported `jQuery` in your page? Make your hidden field visible and see if it does set the value or not. If still not, write a comment.

Comment: I have imported jQuery, and made the fields visible and it doesnt seem to set any of them, they all stay blank. Currently the script tag looks like this.


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#review_form_{{user.user_id}}").children("#id_pk").val("{{user.user_id}}");
        });
      </script>

Comment: Solved. Problem was that the .children couldn't find the id_pk field because it was a child of a p tag, so I just added another .children() to the script and it worked. Thanks again!